# Converting ostream into standard string

Tags: c++, stl, iostream

I am very new to the C++ STL, so this may be trivial. I have a `ostream` variable with some text in it.

```
ostream* pout;
(*pout) << "Some Text";
```

Is there a way to extract the stream and store it in a string of type `char*`?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
     std::ostringstream stream;
     stream << "Some Text";
     std::string str =  stream.str();
     const char* chr = str.c_str();
```

And I explain what's going on in the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512685/a-template-class-in-c/3512819#3512819), which I wrote not an hour ago.

Comment: I get the following error message:

'struct std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >' has no member named 'str'

Comment: Include the necessary headers .`#include <string>` and `#include <sstream>`

Comment: It's not ostream. It is ostringstream

Comment: Note that ostringstream << int seems to return a basic_ostream but won't change the type of the lhs? Thus having something like `oss << value; return oss.str();` will compile while `return (oss << value).str();` will not.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was "convert ostream to std:string"

Comment: @Danny It answers the question stated in the text of the message, not the (different) question asked in the title.

Comment: Weird. From what I see, neither the title nor text of the question contain the word "ostringstream", while your answer does not contain the word "ostream".

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's regarding a `ostream`, not `ostringstream`.

Answer (score 216):

The question was on `ostream` to string, *not* `ostringstream` to string.

For those interested in having the actual question answered (specific to `ostream`), try this:

```
void someFunc(std::ostream out)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << out.rdbuf();
    std::string myString = ss.str();
}
```

Comment: I'll give you points for being a hothead.  Alright.. and for the right answer, heh.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The answer above, marked as correct, does NOT answer the question.

Comment: The parameter should be `std::ostream& out` because `std::ostream` isn't copyable.

Comment: As of C++20, you can avoid the extra string copy by moving it out of the stream instead: `std::string myString = std::move(ss).str();`

Answer (score 8):

Try [`std::ostringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/)

```
   std::ostringstream os;
   os<<"Hello world";
   std::string s=os.str();
   const char *p = s.c_str();
```

Comment: The question isn't about `std::ostringstream` but about `std::ostream`. `std::ostream` doesn't have a method `.str()`.