# Printing either to console or to a string/stream

Tags: c++, c++11

I need a C++ function that dumps some text data (multiple lines) to the console:

```
void DumpData() const
{
    std::cout << "My Data 1" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "My Data 2" << std::endl;
}
```

This should be the default behaviour, however, it must also be possible to pass some other stream object that would be used instead of `std::cout`, something like this:

```
void DumpData(std::ostream& Stream = std::cout) const
{
    Stream << "My Data 1" << std::endl;
    Stream << "My Data 2" << std::endl;
}
```

Now to my questions:

1. What is the correct type I should use for the paramter (`std::ostream&` in this example)?
2. What is the default value, can I use `= std::cout` directly?

Moreover (3.), after the call to this function, if I pass my own stream object, I need to iterate over all strings in this stream line by line. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `std::ostream&` and [`while(std::getline(stream, line)) {...}`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: Question #1: Well, you are using it as an output stream, so, yes, it seems correct. Question #2 could be answered by an attempt to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just try it yourself?

Here's you code [in Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d23749377dee4a2) for `std::cout` and `std::stringstream` as an example (`const`ness of `DumpData` removed obviously):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void DumpData(std::ostream& Stream = std::cout)
{
    Stream << "My Data 1" << std::endl;
    Stream << "My Data 2" << std::endl;
}
int main() {
    DumpData();
    std::stringstream ss;
    DumpData(ss);
    std::string l;
    while(std::getline(ss, l)) {
        std::cout << l << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output is what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 are correct. Your other option is to use `std::ostringstream`, but since `std::cout` is a `std::ostream` you would need to define another function with this signature.

To iterate the custom output, I would [convert the stream to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513173/converting-ostream-into-standard-string#17797823), then use some kind of string splitting to read each line.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Jay 's answer, you could use a template parameter to be able to use a variety of streams such as `std::stringstream` or a `std::iostream` as long as the template parameter supports the `<<` operator.

```
template <typename T> // = decltype(something)
void DumpData(T& Stream = std::cout) const
{
    Stream << "My Data 1" << std::endl;
    Stream << "My Data 2" << std::endl;
}
```

You can take it one step further by ensuring the type T provided overloads the operator `<<`.

Also in some cases, certain (possibly custom) streams may not be able to support `std::endl` so it might be safer to default to using `\n` which is always nicer since it avoid unnecessary flushes.

Comment: Don’t all output stream objects (for `CharT=char` inherit from `std::ostream`? Although I agree templates are preferable to inheritance based interfaces if you can make definition available to all place where is should be used.

Comment: Also `T()` is not equal to `std::cout`.

Comment: Yes, was going for something else when writing the declaration. Fixed now.